# check between two strings if their sequence is maintained

Tags: python, list

If there're two strings how to see if st1 and st2 are sequential? For example

```
st1="coke"
st2="keco"
```

are sequential. But

```
st1="coke"
st2="eock"
```

aren't. The st1 and st2 could be converted to list (& sorted) to check if string containing characters are same and  their lengths are same but how to check their sequence (c-o-k-e & k-e-co are same but c-o-k-e and e-o-c-k are not) are same or not?

Comment: Do you mean you want to check if `st1 == st2[::-1]`

Comment: st1 & st2 will generate True if st1 characters extended cyclic pattern (c-o-k-e-c-o-k-e....) and st2 characters extended cyclic pattern (k-e-c-o-k-e-c-o...) matches  @Heisenberg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend the first string by itself and check if the second string is a substring of that extended string.
In code:

```
st2 in (st1 + st1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use range, and slicing to check:

```
def are_same(str1, str2):
    for i in range(len(str1)):
        if str1[i:] + str1[:i] == str2:
            return True
    
    return False

print(are_same('coke', 'keco')) # True
print(are_same('coke', 'eock')) # False
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you can do:

```
def check(s1,s2):
    return any(''.join([s2[i2-i1] for i2,c2 in enumerate(s2)]) == s1 for i1,c1 in enumerate(s1))

print(check('coke','keco'))
```

Output:

```
True
```